# Laravel - Route::current() not returning the current URL

Tags: php, laravel

I am just learning Laravel.

Currently, I am going through routes.

I want to echo the current URL in Laravel and there was a way to generate it using `Route::current()`.

However, it's not returning the current URL and instead gives the error: `Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Route could not be converted to string`.

I tried this:

```
Route::get('route', function() {
    $route = Route::current();
    return $route;
});
```

Since the error said that it couldn't convert the object into a string, I tried this too:

```
Route::get('route', function() {
    $route = Route::current();
    $myRoute = (string)$route;
    return $myRoute;
});
```

So, how can I return the current URL and output it?

Comment: May I ask why you want to get the current URL in your routes file? You basically just defined the route and should know the URL

Comment: Just for learning purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `url()->current();` according to the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#accessing-the-current-url

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Route::get('route', function() { 
   $route = Route::current();  
   dd($route);
 });
```

Comment: How can I echo the current URL then?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$route` you're trying to return is an object instead of string. To get the path:

`return $route->uri();`

To get the actual request object dumped:

`return var_dump($route);`

`dd($route);`

`return response()->json($route); // json_encode() works too`

Comment: Method `getPath` doesn't exist :)

Comment: @kerbholz answer is correct, I edited my own answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Route::current()->uri()` to show the current route URI.

```
Route::get('route/test/12', function () {
        $route = Route::current()->uri();
        dump($route);
    });
```

will output "route/test/12"